# Carregar fragments em parte da tela?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer tipo um sistema de Tablayout somente em parte da tela. ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde estão as cores verde, azul e laranja seriam os botões das Tabs, e a parte vermelha seria o Fragment carregado, então ao clicar em cada um dos botões (verde, azul e laranja) ele trocaria de Fragment sem afetar o resto do layout. Gostaria de saber se isso é possível e se sim, como o faria? Caso seja de outra jeito sem ser com Fragments também serve.

Se alguém tiver algum exemplo fico agradecido.

Comment: Usa um ViewPager estático (para que o usuário não possa desliza-lo) e um TabLayout normal, mas com background customizado. Resumidamente, sim, é possível.

Comment: @itscorey teria algum exemplo ou link?

Comment: O static viewpager tu encontra aqui: https://gist.github.com/itscorey/d9c747aaea785da08351bb68cffdbaac

Comment: Tu pode utilizar ele como View no XML mesmo, sem problemas. O TabLayout você vê mais sobre aqui: https://materialdoc.com/components/tabs/ | http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_Tabbed_Interface_using_the_TabLayout_Component

Comment: @itscorey muito obrigado, vou dar uma lida aqui